# What is the source for the idea that a woman can marry any man?

Tags: women, marriage

I have heard a few times the idea that a woman can theoretically marry any man (and be happy), as long as she works on herself. Presumably because the happiness of the relationship depends on the woman, or because a woman has the ability to change her husband for the good, i.e. Leah and Dinah had the potential to turn Esav around.

Has anyone else heard of this idea, or know what the source is?

Answer (score 5):

Source: Kidushin Daf 7a (and again in 41a):

> דהא איתתא ניחא לה בכל דהו כדריש לקיש דאמר ריש לקיש טב למיתב טן דו מלמיתב ארמלו

*Since a woman is happy to marry anybody, in accordance with Reish Lakish who said: A [woman] prefers to be "a couple" rather than being single.*

Comment: Does this mean she will be equally happy in any relationship? It just means its better than nothing. I don't see how that answers the ops question

Comment: @DoubleAA: The question was not if she'd be "equally happy in any relationship" but "that a woman can theoretically marry any man (and be happy)". Reish Lakish asserts that she's happier being married than being single. He doesn't say "how happy" - but she's at least somewhat happy.

Comment: Calling the lesser of two evils "somewhat happy" is a little bit of a stretch. You can construct lots of morbid examples to prove that to yourself

Comment: @DoubleAA I am 99.99999% sure that this is the source for the idea the op refers to. It jumped right in to my head the second I finished reading the question. It can certainly be interpreted that way, and it evidently was when it was related to the op.

Comment: @BabySeal It's davka not what I thought the OP referred to. I thought he was referring to the issue of the bat kol and shidduchim (isn't there an alleged gender non-parellel in the way that gemara is phrased? something like that; don't remember how it goes)

Comment: @DoubleAA not familiar with that, what's the source/context? In any event I think this source is a perfectly reasonable one to cite. Agree to disagree, I guess.

Comment: This source is used to prove that a woman may appoint a messenger to be married, even without meeting the man, since she'll be happy with anyone.

Comment: This is a mistranslation. Nicha Lei does not mean happy as in a “happy marriage”. At most it means “she wants” or “she prefers”.